# Combining column texts in a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a set of data that currently looks like this:[image: current data format]

For reporting purposes, I have to pivot the InterviewNotes column. Here is as far as I've gotten:

```
SELECT CandidateId, JobId, [1] AS Int1, [2] AS Int2, [3] AS Int3
FROM (SELECT CandidateId, JobId, InterviewNotes, InterviewNo FROM dbo.FactInterview) AS sourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(InterviewNotes) FOR InterviewNo IN ([1],[2],[3])
) AS PivotTable
```

For each column, I'd like to display: InterviewName, InterviewDt, InterviewNotes concatenated. Such as:

```
Int1: InterviewerName - InterviewDt - InterviewNotes
Int2: InterviewerName - InterviewDt - InterviewNotes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `InterviewerName`, `InterviewDt` and `InterviewNotes` concatenated together to be displayed in the final column, then concatenate the values before the PIVOT:

```
SELECT CandidateId, JobId, [1] AS Int1, [2] AS Int2, [3] AS Int3
FROM 
(
    SELECT CandidateId, JobId, InterviewNo, 
        InterviewNotes = InterviewerName + ' - '+ convert(varchar(10), InterviewDt, 120) +' - '+ InterviewNotes
    FROM dbo.FactInterview
) AS sourceTable
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(InterviewNotes) FOR InterviewNo IN ([1],[2],[3])
) AS PivotTable
```